# Find neigbouring vertices of a vertex

Tags: three.js, 3d, vertex, vertices, cannon.js

I am working on a project to find the neighbouring vertices of a vertex for example in an rectangular mesh for a particular vertex (Xi , Yj , Zk) the  neighbouring vertices would be

```
Xi+1 , Yj , Zk (right vertex)
Xi-1 , Yj , Zk (left vertex)
Xi , Yj+1 , Zk (top vertex)
Xi , Yj-1 , Zk (bottom vertex)
Xi , Yj , Zk+1 (front vertex)
Xi , Yj , Zk-1 (back vertex)
```

But how could they be found for a triangular mesh .
Is there any code availabe to find the vertices near them or within a certain range.

I am currently working with js script in particular three.js script 
I loaded a 3d obj model which would be a buffer geometry .Then I got the vertices of the mesh using its geometry attributes . Now for each vertex I wanted to find its connected vertices ... Like to find the vertices with which the given vertex shares its edges..
Any small citation would be of  great help .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I commented on Mugen87's answer also. If I'm reading the question right, you want the neighbors within the triangles, not within a kind of local space. Regardless, I think this question needs a little more focus. Specifically, what type of geometry are you working with? `Geometry`? `BufferGeometry`? If it's the latter, is it indexed?

Comment: yeah right not within a local space..But  also more specifically only those  that are directly connected like the ones that it is surrounded by and sharing its edge.. And it  is a BufferGeometry which is indexed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any code availabe to find the vertices near them or within a certain range.

No, at least not in the repository. However, you can implement a basic solution by yourself. The idea is to create an instance of [THREE.Sphere](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere) for representing the concept of *neighborhood*. The `center` property would be your vertex and `radius` property would be your range. You can then iterate over all other vertices and call [THREE.Sphere.containsPoint()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere.containsPoint) to verify if a vertex lies in the defined neighborhood.

`three.js R115`

Comment: Thanks. Will try that out ...But  this  method could also get the vertices that are not linked to the center vertex.. How can I make sure to get only those connected with the center vertex.

Comment: What do you mean with "connected with the center vertex"? If you are referring to the other vertices of a triangle, well, you can derive this information from the buffer geometry. Depending on whether is an indexed or non-indexed you have to evaluate the `position` buffer attribute or the respective index.

Comment: I read @PopupDev 's request as the latter. I was writing up a response, but it started getting really in-depth. I think the question requires more focus to concentrate on a single problem, or at least reduce the question's scope by defining exactly what type of geometry is being used and the draw mode.

Comment: I loaded a 3d obj model which would be a buffer geometry .Then I got the vertices of the mesh using its geometry attributes . Now for each vertex I wanted to find its connected vertices ... Like to find the vertices with which the given vertex shares its edges..

Answer (score 1):

Three.js doesn't have something out of the box, but there is a script you might be able to modify to get the desired result.

The [SubdivisionModifier](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=subdi#webgl_modifier_subdivision) needs to compare adjacent vertex positions to calculate position averages. In order to achieve this, it converts a BufferGeometry to a [Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry) with

`geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geometry );`

Then it uses each edge to look up which two triangles (Faces) are connected to that edge. You can see this in its [source code, line 216](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js#L208). If you copy-paste this script to your source code, you can make modifications to do what you want:

1. Search only for edges that are connected to your vertex.
2. Return the vertices that are at the other side of those edges.

I understand this is not a complete answer, but it's the closest suggestion I can think of that might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the  response ..But I am beginner and I couldn't make it  work . Could  you make  the  code for it ..

Comment: @PopupDev I'd be happy to write the code for you as a paid contract. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: could I know  how much it would cost .. Just out of curiosity.